# How can i get individual sequential IP blocks from an IP Range?

Tags: java, ip-address

Given an ip range such as ***41.216.124.0-41.216.127.27***, i would like to get the following:

41.216.124.`*`

41.216.125.`*`

41.216.126.`*`

41.216.127.`*`

similarly given ***128.1.0.1-191.255.255.254*** i would like to list them individually
128.1.0.1-255

128.1.1-255.`*`

128.2-255.`*`.`*`

129-190.`*`.`*`

191.0-254.`*`.`*`

191.255.`*`

191.255.255.`*`

I have tried various ways including using regex to match fields which are non repeating and trying to work out the difference. I came across a very good library https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/ by https://stackoverflow.com/users/6801443/sean-f I have tried the following, but cant seem to find a way to do it in the documentation.

````
 var ipRange1 = "128.1.0.1-191.255.255.254"; //ipRange1 example
 var ipRange2 = "41.216.124.0-41.216.127.27"; //ipRange2 example
 import inet.ipaddr.IPAddress;
 import inet.ipaddr.IPAddressSeqRange;
 import inet.ipaddr.IPAddressString; 
 String[] subString = ipRange2.split("-");  
 IPAddressString startIP = new IPAddressString(subString[0]);
 IPAddressString endIP = new IPAddressString(subString[1]);
 IPAddress one = startIP.getAddress(), two = endIP.getAddress();
 IPAddressSeqRange range = one.toSequentialRange(two);
 var ips = new HashSet<String>();
 IPAddress blocks[] = range.spanWithSequentialBlocks(); // 41.216.124-126.```*```
````

Is there anyway to do it in Java even without this library? The API i am trying to query uses IP prefix which is why i am going to all the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my initial stab.  You must realize that the ranges you are talking about are quite large.  I am using longs to avoid signed integer problems in my `LongStream` range.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printIPs("192.148.233.0", "192.148.245.3", 32);

    }

    public static void printIPs(String start, String end, int mask) {
        LongStream.rangeClosed(toLong(start, mask), toLong(end, mask))
                .mapToObj(ip-> toIP(ip, mask))
                .forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    public static String toIP(long lv, int mask) {
        lv <<= (32-mask);
        String ip = String.join(".",
                Long.toString((lv >> 24) & 0xFF),
                Long.toString((lv >> 16) & 0xFF),
                Long.toString((lv >> 8) & 0xFF),
                Long.toString(lv & 0xFF));
        return ip;
    }

    public static long toLong(String ip, int mask) {
        String[] n = ip.split("\\.");

        long v = Integer.valueOf(n[0]);
        v <<= 8;
        v |= Integer.valueOf(n[1]);
        v <<= 8;
        v |= Integer.valueOf(n[2]);
        v <<= 8;
        v |= Integer.valueOf(n[3]);

        return v >> (32-mask);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Not the exact solution i wanted but this taught a lot and it's a great starting point.

Comment: I modified the program to provide additional capability. I added a CIDR "mask" to specify how you want the output. By passing in 32 as the third parameter, it behaves like it always did. If you provide a 16 for example, it will print all /16's between the two values, ignoring the insignficant bits.